# Invalid identifier when using subset query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(adults+children) as qty from reservation where id = 11407) as qty,
SUM((price * qty) - (price * nvl(qty_excluded,0))) 
FROM reservation_product
WHERE id = 11407
```

I get the following message: qty invalid identifier.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50796016/edit) to include both table definitions and sample data. This looks like you're just trying to use a column alias in the same level of query, which isn't allowed; but it can probably be simplified anyway.

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole,that's correct, I'm trying to use the column alias in the same level of the query.

Comment: `reservation_product` probably doesn't have a column `qty`. You expect the DBMS to evaluate the `qty` expression first and then use this when evaluating the other expression. This is not the case.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes, reservation_product holds no qty column, how do i change the query to take the qty in conideration?

Comment: You can move a subquery to the `FROM` clause. However, I'm confused with the ID columns. An ID should uniquely identify a record in a table, but you treat them as if they were non-unique columns. A reservation 11407 should have nothing to do with a reservation product 11407 (or only because of mere coincidence). Please explain.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in this case these both tables contain the same id for a specific record. when you say move a subquery to the from, how exactly should i do that?

Comment: So ID does not identify a reservation, but some project or transaction or location or whatever? Just an inadequate column name in both tables?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes exactly :)

Comment: I suppose your query is somewhat off. Maybe you'd like to tell us what you are trying to do. Then show sample data and expected result. I have posted an answer on how to transfer your subquery from `SELECT` to `FROM`, but I doubt this query is actually what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks strange. There is some ID in the tables, and you say it's neither their ID, nor the reservation ID. But you have it in both tables, so a reservation can refer to a different  as its reservation products do.

And in your query you don't care whether the reservation products you select belong to the reservations you select.

Anyway, your query simply transfered is:

```
SELECT MAX(r.qty),
SUM((rp.price * r.qty) - (rp.price * nvl(rp.qty_excluded,0))) 
FROM reservation_product rp
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(adults+children) as qty 
  FROM reservation 
  WHERE id = 11407
) r
WHERE id = 11407;
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, now I am getting not a single group group function

Comment: Sorry. You need some aggregation on `r.qty` in order to show it. I've corrected my answer. (Instead of pseudo `MAX` you could also use a pseudo `GROUP BY`, by the way, as we are dealing with one `r.qty` only.)